# Getting ajax request response node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I have a html page that triggers an ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/usernamecheck',
                data: {"username":username},
                success: function(taken){
                    if(taken === 0){
                        $('#error').text('The username' + username + ' is available!')
                    }else{
                        $('#error').text('The username' + username + ' is not available')
                    }
                },
                dataType: "json"
            })
```

this is my node.js code:

```
exports.usernameCheck = function(req,res){
var db;
db = require('./../custom_modules/db.js');
var username = req.body.username;
db.users.find({username:username},function(err,users){

    console.log(username)
    if(users.length === 0){
        //return 0
    }else{
        //return1
    }
})
```

and I want to respond to this ajax with node.js request but am a little unsure of how to do so?

Comment: Well the first thing you'd have to do is have a web server written and have it respond to the post request to /usernamecheck. Have you written anything for node yet? I don't think your question is specific enough to really give a good answer.

Comment: @travis I have, i'll update my question

Comment: What your AJAX is doing is just making a normal HTTP request via Javascript. If you have a web server set up, you just respond as you would if someone entered the URL into their browser (albeit with json or something).

Comment: @jli could you give me an example of code to do this? I use express and render html pages using `res.render()` what is the equivelent for sending JSON?

Comment: `res.send()` can take objects and will JSON.stringify them, too, now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery ajax `dataType` represents the data your're expecting back from the server. I would leave this as json and just change other parts of your code to accommodate the data type.

**Client**

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/usernamecheck',
  data: {"username":username},
  success: function(response){
    if( response.taken === true){
      $('#error').text('The username' + username + ' is available!')
    }else{
      $('#error').text('The username' + username + ' is not available')
    }
  },
  dataType: "json"
})
```

**Node**

```
db.users.find({username:username},function(err,users){
  res.json({taken: users.length !== 0})
})
```

Comment: Although since he's now mentioned he's using express: `res.json()` rather than `res.write(JSON.stringify())`. Also, could do `taken: users.length !== 0` to cut out that branching.